# ioctl(tcpCnx->get_fd(), I_SRDOPT, RMSGN) coomand not working on LINUX RH7.4

Tags: c++, linux, ioctl

I am using following ioctl function in a `C++` program:

```
ioctl(tcpCnx->get_fd(), I_SRDOPT, RMSGN);
```

It is working fine on LINUX RH 6.3.But when I compile it on LINUX RH 7.4 following error is thrown :

```
**d.cxx: In member function 'virtual void diameterClient::Accept(int)':
d.cxx:447:26: error: 'I_SRDOPT' was not declared in this scope
  ioctl(tcpCnx->get_fd(), I_SRDOPT, RMSGN); 
                          ^
d.cxx:447:36: error: 'RMSGN' was not declared in this scope
  ioctl(tcpCnx->get_fd(), I_SRDOPT, RMSGN);  
                                    ^
d.cxx:447:41: error: 'ioctl' was not declared in this scope 
  ioctl(tcpCnx->get_fd(), I_SRDOPT, RMSGN);**
```

When I debugged I found that on LINUX RH 6.3 stropts.h is included.
But this file is not present on LINUX RH 7.4.

Please suggest how can I compile my program on LINUX RH 7.4.

Comment: This is an omission [by purpose](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=656245).

Comment: Sounds like you can't do this anymore. If you provide more context, odds are good someone can provide a work-around suited to your use case.